# Is it possible to format the date inside an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json-ld

Is something like this possible? Trying to format the date `formatted_short`

```
<Generic type="startDate" jsonldtype="DateTime" schema={{ 
  startDate: `${props.dates[0].start_date.formatted_short.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`,
  endDate: `${props.dates[0].end_date.formatted_short}`,
  doorTime: `${props.dates[0].start_date.time}`,
}}/>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to format a Date object in Javascript? That's something that's easy to research, depending on how much formatting options you need

Comment: I have been researching how to format a date and have used moment.js before successfully. I just am unsure of how to do it in this context. I have tried: startDate: `{Moment(${props.dates[0].start_date.formatted_short}).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`,

Comment: it's better to create a function and do this stuff on it and just call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment Example:

```
<Generic type="startDate" jsonldtype="Date" schema={{ 
  startDate: Moment(`${props.dates[0].start_date.formatted_short}`).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),   
  endDate: Moment(`${props.dates[0].end_date.formatted_short}`).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  doorTime: Moment(`${props.dates[0].start_date.time}`).format('hh:mm:ss')
}}/>
```

Should anybody need it

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-moment for to formart date.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#formatting

You can use like this;

```
import React  from 'react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // format : your format.
            <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">
                1976-04-19T12:59-0500 // your date string
            </Moment>
        );
    }
}
```